# JQuery Supersized plugin not transitioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, supersized

I have set up the JQuery Plugin Supersized (http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) and copied the set up from the example, replacing their images with my own.

Whilst the first image is showing fine, it does not transition to the 2nd image and the back and next arrows do not appear.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Setup is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/supersized.core.css" />
<script src="js/supersized.core.3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">



        jQuery(function($){

        $.supersized({

        // Functionality
        slideshow:1,    // Slideshow on/off
        autoplay:1, // Slideshow starts playing automatically
        start_slide:1,  // Start slide (0 is random)
        stop_loop:0,    // Pauses slideshow on last slide
        random:0,   // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
        slide_interval:3000, // Length between transitions
        transition:6,   // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
        transition_speed:1000,  // Speed of transition
        new_window:1,   // Image links open in new window/tab
        pause_hover:0,  // Pause slideshow on hover
        keyboard_nav:1, // Keyboard navigation on/off
        performance:1,  // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
        image_protect:1,// Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

        // Size & Position                         
        min_width:0,    // Min width allowed (in pixels)
        min_height:0,   // Min height allowed (in pixels)
        vertical_center:1,  // Vertically center background
        horizontal_center:1,    // Horizontally center background
        fit_always:0,       // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
        fit_portrait:1,     // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
        fit_landscape:0,    // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

        // Components                           
        slide_links:'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'number', 'name', 'blank')
        thumb_links:1,      // Individual thumb links for each slide
        thumbnail_navigation:0, // Thumbnail navigation
        slides : [      // Slideshow Images
                                                                {image : 'assets/images/Retouch_096.jpg', title : '', thumb : '', url : 'assets/images/Retouch_096.jpg'},
                                                                {image : 'assets/images/rooftop.jpg', title : '', thumb : '', url : 'assets/images/rooftop.jpg'}
                                                        ],

        // Theme Options               
        progress_bar:0, // Timer for each slide                         
        mouse_scrub:0

            });
        });



    </script>
```

Comment: Do you have a live URL of your code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK - I finally figured it out: I was linking off to supersized.core.3.2.1.min.js when I should have used: supersized.3.2.7.min.js for the slider (wonderful documentation on the site...)

Comment: I was having the same issue and made the same mistake.  There is something about the word 'core' that made me believe that was the appropriate file I needed.

Comment: Thanks, I was just about to throw the computer out the window. Core = Main Files NOT!

Comment: Same issue, Thanks alot!